# How to block out all past dates in ReactJS FullCalendar wrapper?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to figure out how to block out all past days in my calendar to prevent users from scheduling an appointment and I'm not able to get it to work.

For example, today is the 8th of November I want to block out all previous days from being selected.

I looked online and there are many SO articles on how to do this with other languages but I'm using the ReactJS FullCalendar wrapper which doesn't have an option to pass into the props to deal with this. I looked at there documentation and I tried to play around with there API and I wasn't able to figure it out.

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

// Time Slots

const ScheduleAppointment = (props) => {

  const someMethod = () => {
    let calendarApi = calendarRef.current.getApi();
    let changeMinDate =
      (calendarApi.currentDataManager.data.dateProfile.validRange = {
        start: "2021-11-08",
        end: null
      });
    console.log("calendarapi11 is..", changeMinDate);
    console.log("calendarapi222 is..", calendarApi);
  };
  
 useEffect(() => {
    someMethod();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="fluid-container">
      <FullCalendar
              plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
              initialView="dayGridMonth"
              dateClick={handleDateClick}
              selectable={true}
              ref={calendarRef}
              // this doesn't work I have to manually get into the api via refs
              //validRange = {
                //start: '2021-11-08',
                //end: null
              //}
            />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ScheduleAppointment;
```

Comment: In what way does the validRange not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: I dont get an error but when I look in FullCalendar for ReactJS it doesn't gray out the dates that I specified in the start. I need to note that I'm using the ReactJS fullcalendar wrapper which I havent found out how to modify the validrange anywhere on google except through the api via refs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect that

```
validRange = {{
               start: '2021-11-08',
               end: null
             }}
```

should work.

The outer set of `{ }`s denotes the start and end of the property value - just like it does on the `plugins` property, for example. Then the inner ones are part of the JS object containing the range data.

Comment: It works! I was missing the extra set of curly brackets thank you! :)